# Python strange error using a regex

Tags: python, regex

This is my code

```
>>> string="a 32GB  512MB "
>>> regex="(\d{1,4})(,|.){0,1}(\d{1,2}){0,1}\s*(KB|MB|GB)"
>>> import re
>>> res = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print res
[('32', '', '', 'GB'), ('512', '', '', 'MB')]
>>> res=res[len(res)-1]
>>> print res
('512', '', '', 'MB')
>>> res="".join(res[0])
>>> print res
512
```

I can't understand why the

```
res="".join(res[0])
```

return 512 instead of 512MB

Comment: IMHO, not that strange. You are joining only first string in the tuple. Do `res="".join(res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this statement of urs

```
res="".join(res[0])
```

This is because you have already done

```
res=res[len(res)-1]
```

which makes `res` = `('512', '', '', 'MB')`.

You just need to `join` `res` not `res[0]` as `res[0]` would be `512`.

You can check this way

```
string="a 32GB  512MB "
regex="(\d{1,4})(,|.){0,1}(\d{1,2}){0,1}\s*(KB|MB|GB)"
import re
res = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)

print "".join(res[0])
print "".join(res[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the index index specified ie, `[0]` which fetch only the first element.

```
res = "".join(res)
```

You must get the desired output without joining if you turn all capturing groups to non-capturing groups.

```
regex = r"\b\d{1,4}[,.]?(?:\d{1,2})?\s*(?:KB|MB|GB)\b"
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> string="a 32GB  512MB "
>>> res = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,4}[,.]?(?:\d{1,2})?\s*(?:KB|MB|GB)\b", string, re.I)
>>> res
['32GB', '512MB']
>>> res[-1]
'512MB'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`res[0]` is the string `'512'`.  Since strings are iterable, you can use `str.join` on them.  In this case, you're joining each character with an empty string resulting in the original string.

It seems that you want to join the entire tuple:  `''.join(res)`